# Regular Expression (avoid float numbers)

Tags: php, regex, floating-point, numbers

I want a pattern to create a "is_id()" function to validate user input before mysql query. The pattern most contain ONLY numbers, my problem is avoid the float numbers:

```
function is_id($id) {          
    $pattern = "/^[0-9]+/";      
        if(preg_match($pattern,$id)) {      
            echo "ok";      
        } else {      
            echo "error";       
        }    
} 


is_id(0) // error  
is_id(-5) // error  
is_id(-5.5) // error  
is_id(1.5) // ok <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM  
is_id(10) // ok  
is_id("5") // ok  
is_id("string") // error
```

Comment: This is valid as well, is_id(0) you have it displaying // error

Comment: Surely there exists a function to determine whether a value looks like a number; there should not be a need to construct a regex for this.

Comment: Numbers are not strings, and regular expressions should never EVER Be used to validate integer's, PHP Native functions are what you should be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the trailing `$` in your pattern. In `is_id(1.5)` your pattern is matching the `1` and stopping. If you add a trailing `$` (as in `^[0-9]+$`) then the pattern will need to match the entire input to succeed.

Answer (score 6):

$ denotes the end of a line/string to match.

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this, you can use a simple check like so:

```
function is_id($id)
{
    return ((is_numeric($id) || is_int($id)) && !is_float($id)) && $id > -1
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
var_dump(is_id(0));        // false - are we indexing from 0 or 1 ?
var_dump(is_id(-5));       // false
var_dump(is_id(-5.5));     // false
var_dump(is_id(1.5));      // false
var_dump(is_id(10));       // true
var_dump(is_id("5"));      // true
var_dump(is_id("string")); // false
```

---

I favour ircmaxell's answer.

Comment: This does work but I think the OP is looking for whole numbers from his example. As "5e3" would be a valid number with your function

Comment: `var_dump(is_numeric(1.5));` yields `bool(true)`.  So you'd need to add an additional check to see if it's an integer...

Comment: @ircmaxell he had it in the original post: return ((is_numeric($id) || is_int($id)) && $id > -1);

Comment: My code may not be perfect but the advice is not to use regular expressions to validate integers, floats etc.

Comment: @Phill, @Robert: `php -r '$id = 5.5; var_dump(((is_numeric($id) || is_int($id)) && $id > -1));'` yields `bool(true)`, which says `1.5` is true.  So further revision needed...

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regex?  Why not check types (this isn't as tiny as the regex, but it may be more semantically appropriate)

```
function is_id($n) {
    return is_numeric($n) && floor($n) == $n && $n > 0;
}
```

`is_numeric()` verifies that it's either a float, an int, or a number than can be converted.

`floor($n) == $n` checks to see if it's indeed an integer.

`$n > 0` checks to see if it's greater than 0.

Done...

Comment: Nice thinking with the `floor` +1

Comment: @Robert: it's dirty, and I can't stand it.  But afaik that's the only way of handling everything that PHP will convert into a float (`1.5`, `"1.5"`, etc) **and** not missing things like `1.0` (which is really an int, but stored as a float)...